# Python: Reading from Queue slows the ability to write to Queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I encountered a very puzzling issue while working with Python's multiprocessing module.

The setup is pretty typical. My machine has 32 cores and 244 GB of RAM (thank you AWS). One process to write to an ingestion queue. N processes to do the work I need done, process_data(). M processes to do some preaggregation, preaggregate_results(). One process to do the final aggregation and write the output.

If N is 'large' and M is only 1 or 2, then process_data() is very fast. It basically keeps up with the ingestion process. But since M is very small, the preaggregation is relatively slow and the intermediate_results queue bloats.

Here is the heart of the issue. Every increase in M results in a MARKED decrease in process_data()'s ability to write to the intermediate_results queue. In fact, if N==M==12, the process is so slow that it's not even reasonable to wait for the job to finish. process_data() goes from pacing with the ingestion queue to getting left in the dust.

I included some skeleton code below that just outlines the work flow I'm talking about. It's not to be taken literally. I'm curious if anyone else has encountered this issue before and knows how to solve it. I've talked to many of my coworkers (including code review) and they are just as stumped as I am.

I use multiprocessing all the time with success. This is the first time I've encountered this issue. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import pandas as pd
import csv

KILL_TOKEN = 'STOP'
NUM_PROCESS_DATA = 14
NUM_PROCESS_PREAGGREGATE = 1


def ingest_data(ingestion_queue):
    ...pandas data munging      
    for blah in univariate_data.itertuples():
        ... write to ingestion_queue


def process_data(ingestion_queue, intermediate_results):    
    while True:
        data = ingestion_queue.get()
        if data == KILL_TOKEN:
            break
        ... process data
        ... write to intermediate_results

def preaggregate_results(intermediate_results, output_queue):    
    while True:       
        data = intermediate_results.get()
        if data == KILL_TOKEN:
            break
        ... preaggregation
    ... write to output_queue after kill token is received

def process_output(output_queue):    
    while True:       
        data = output_queue.get()
        if data == KILL_TOKEN:
            break
        ... final aggregation
    ... write results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ... the usual
```

Comment: If you think that program is slow on a big amount of small packets to process - group them and retrieve not a single item from the queue but a set of items which will give required load time for a worker process.